# How to find Speed, Velocity, and Acceleration between two point $X_1, Y_1, Z_1$ and $X_2, Y_2, Z_2$

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I have Excel sheet for $X, Y, Z$ coordinates. This data represent a locations for different points where hand moving during a 30fps video.

I am trying to calculate Speed, Velocity, and Acceleration for each row in that excel sheet.

I am not sure what is the accurate EQUATION to do that.

Many thanks :)

Sample Data:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\text{Frame_No} & \text{X} & \text{Y} & \text{Z} & \text{Speed} & \text{Velocity} & \text{Acceleration} \\ 
1 & 43.38 & 16.81 & 105.65 \\ \hline
2 & 43.4 & 16.81 & 105.67 \\ \hline
3 & 43.41 & 16.8 & 105.68 \\ \hline
4 & 43.42 & 16.79 & 105.7 \\ \hline
5 & 43.42 & 16.76 & 105.7 \\ \hline
6 & 43.41 & 16.73 & 105.69 \\ \hline
7 & 43.41 & 16.72 & 105.67 \\ \hline
8 & 43.41 & 16.7 & 105.64 \\ \hline
9 & 43.4 & 16.68 & 105.6 \\ \hline
10 & 43.39 & 16.65 & 105.57 \\ \hline
11 & 43.38 & 16.67 & 105.55 \\ \hline
12 & 43.37 & 16.71 & 105.55 \\ \hline
13 & 43.38 & 16.77 & 105.53 \\ \hline
14 & 43.35 & 16.82 & 105.56 \\ \hline
15 & 43.22 & 16.65 & 105.71 \\ \hline
16 & 43.05 & 16.47 & 106.23 \\ \hline
17 & 42.74 & 16.62 & 108 \\ \hline
18 & 42.56 & 16.85 & 110.82 \\ \hline
19 & 42.78 & 17.35 & 114.35 \\ \hline
20 & 43.16 & 18.02 & 118.83 \\ \hline
21 & 43.68 & 18.85 & 125.11 \\ \hline
22 & 43.62 & 19.01 & 131.7 \\ \hline
23 & 43.09 & 18.61 & 136.21 \\ \hline
24 & 42.28 & 18.16 & 140.04 \\ \hline
25 & 40.7 & 17.43 & 144.64 \\ \hline
26 & 38.91 & 16.52 & 148.23 \\ \hline
27 & 38.32 & 16.22 & 149.2 \\ \hline
28 & 38.17 & 16.31 & 149.37 \\ \hline
29 & 37.57 & 16.2 & 150.07 \\ \hline
30 & 36.91 & 16.16 & 150.91 \\ \hline
31 & 35.94 & 16.24 & 152.08 \\ \hline
32 & 35.71 & 16.73 & 153.16 \\ \hline
33 & 37.88 & 18 & 153.8 \\ \hline
34 & 41.31 & 19.65 & 153.86 \\ \hline
35 & 45.52 & 22.44 & 152.69 \\ \hline
36 & 48.05 & 24.79 & 150.25 \\ \hline
37 & 47.37 & 24.36 & 149.11 \\ \hline
38 & 45.85 & 23.1 & 148.55 \\ \hline
39 & 45.21 & 22.3 & 148.03 \\ \hline
40 & 43.6 & 21.69 & 147.17 \\ \hline
41 & 39.77 & 20.26 & 145.09 \\ \hline
42 & 36 & 18.02 & 142.97 \\ \hline
43 & 32.52 & 16.68 & 141.57 \\ \hline
44 & 30.59 & 15.8 & 140.88 \\ \hline
45 & 31.31 & 15.97 & 141.25 \\ \hline
46 & 32.74 & 16.8 & 141.73 \\ \hline
47 & 34 & 18 & 141.78 \\ \hline
48 & 35.42 & 19.66 & 141.63 \\ \hline
49 & 37.02 & 22.23 & 141.26 \\ \hline
50 & 38.11 & 24.22 & 140.84 \\ \hline
51 & 38.38 & 24.66 & 140.7 \\ \hline
52 & 38.57 & 25.17 & 140.2 \\ \hline
53 & 39.02 & 26.41 & 138.78 \\ \hline
54 & 39.44 & 27.32 & 137.71 \\ \hline
55 & 39.66 & 27.76 & 137.6 \\ \hline
56 & 39.51 & 28.01 & 137.44 \\ \hline
57 & 39 & 28.24 & 136.61 \\ \hline
58 & 37.68 & 27.55 & 137.23 \\ \hline
59 & 34.66 & 24.85 & 139.67 \\ \hline
60 & 31.32 & 21.96 & 140.98 \\ \hline
61 & 28.95 & 19.86 & 141.6 \\ \hline
62 & 27.23 & 18.03 & 142.29 \\ \hline
63 & 25.91 & 16.35 & 143.13 \\ \hline
64 & 25.65 & 16.15 & 143.5 \\ \hline
65 & 26.73 & 18.07 & 143.36 \\ \hline
66 & 27.87 & 19.58 & 143.25 \\ \hline
67 & 28.57 & 20.3 & 143.24 \\ \hline
68 & 29.19 & 20.84 & 143.27 \\ \hline
69 & 29.67 & 21.06 & 143.33 \\ \hline
70 & 30.83 & 22.67 & 143.49 \\ \hline
71 & 33.28 & 25.7 & 144.25 \\ \hline
72 & 35.66 & 28.29 & 144.74 \\ \hline
73 & 37.64 & 30.59 & 144.27 \\ \hline
74 & 39.24 & 32.45 & 144.18 \\ \hline
75 & 40.32 & 34.06 & 144.63 \\ \hline
76 & 41.01 & 35.05 & 144.86 \\ \hline
77 & 41.35 & 35.4 & 144.75 \\ \hline
78 & 41.5 & 35.57 & 144.66 \\ \hline
79 & 41.47 & 35.58 & 144.6 \\ \hline
80 & 41.47 & 35.52 & 144.64 \\ \hline
81 & 41.52 & 35.41 & 144.76 \\ \hline
82 & 41.54 & 35.29 & 144.89 \\ \hline
83 & 41.54 & 35.14 & 145.01 \\ \hline
84 & 41.56 & 35.01 & 145.19 \\ \hline
85 & 41.6 & 34.89 & 145.44 \\ \hline
86 & 41.62 & 34.83 & 145.56 \\ \hline
87 & 41.63 & 34.84 & 145.56 \\ \hline
88 & 41.6 & 34.8 & 145.69 \\ \hline
89 & 41.54 & 34.72 & 145.94 \\ \hline
90 & 41.54 & 34.59 & 146.23 \\ \hline
91 & 41.59 & 34.42 & 146.56 \\ \hline
92 & 41.61 & 34.33 & 146.85 \\ \hline
93 & 41.6 & 34.3 & 147.09 \\ \hline
94 & 41.55 & 34.27 & 147.21 \\ \hline
95 & 41.46 & 34.26 & 147.21 \\ \hline
96 & 41.41 & 34.26 & 147.17 \\ \hline
97 & 41.39 & 34.28 & 147.08 \\ \hline
98 & 41.4 & 34.32 & 147.04 \\ \hline
99 & 41.39 & 34.31 & 147 \\ \hline
100 & 40.96 & 33.87 & 147.05 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: assuming the motion is a straight line, you can use formula $d=v_it+0.5at^2$. You will need initial velocity $v_i$, you can calculate distance between two points and you can find time lapsed when you are watching video.

Comment: Do you know what speed, velocity and acceleration are measured? Note that speed is often used as the same term as velocity so I would expect them to be equal, unless you use a strange naming convention. Since you have the frame rate you essentially can express the position as a function of time. The difference between two positions is achieved in a certain time, what does that mean for the speed? Show us what you have tried!

Comment: Speed and Velocity are different.
Speed is scalar, Velocity is vector.
Here is some details https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dCrkp8qgLU&t=301s

Comment: @Jan 
Based on the above table I am supposing hte following three equations:
Speed=SQRT((B2-B3)^2+(C3-C2)^2+(D3-D2)^2) / (A3-A2). 
Velocity=((B2-B3)+(C3-C2)+(D3-D2)) / (A3-A2).
Acceleration=(F3-F2)/(A3-A2).

BUT, I am not 100% sure if these equations are the correct ones!